# Start a movie on click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been having difficulty getting my movie to start playing once a certain button is hit. I can get it to work with void Start() but then the video starts playing as soon as the scene is loaded which I don't want.  I have tried this for when the button is pressed to start playing the movie.

```
    public MovieTexture myMovie;
    public RawImage myLayer;
    private new AudioSource audio;

    public void onClick()
    {
        GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = myMovie as MovieTexture;

        audio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
        audio.clip = myMovie.audioClip;
        myMovie.Play ();
        audio.Play ();


    }
```

The movie will show but not actually play. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but as I am a noob at coding I can't figure out what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is myMovie ever set in the class constructor?

Comment: Are you sure onClick is being called? Usually it is used the method OnMouseDown to detect clicks https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html
And the object will need to have a collider or an GUIElement to detect the click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a custom method which will contain

```
void Play()
{
    myMovie.Play ();
    audio.Play ();
}
```

and assign it to the button component in the inspector

EDIT:
I meant, don't use onClick as you use Start etc, it's not executable like that. There are 2 ways:

1) You make a custom method (called whetever you want) e.g as I listed above and assign it to the onClick field in the inspector, press +, add a script and select a method from that script; 
[image]

2)

```
public Button yourButton;

    void Start () {
        Button btn = yourButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    void TaskOnClick(){
        Debug.Log ("You have clicked the button!");
    }
```

like in the reference: docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html

Comment: Yeah that's what I was trying to do with the code above, I'm sorry if that wasn't clear.  When I push the button that executes onClick the movie appears but doesn't work.

Comment: I finally got it to work. I changed my method name from onClick to playMovie and assigned it to the movie panel instead of a movie controller and now it works beautifully. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Video Player using Create -> Video -> Video Player

Set video player video clip, Render Mode as Camera Far Plane and Select camera as Main Camera

[image]

Create script as given below. Just call the playMovie() method in any button event

[image]

[image]